# How to call .KSH script or .sh script from MQFTE presource call

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I need the exact syntax to call a .ksh script as part of MQFTE presource call.

I am aware of the **-presrc** argument in the **fteCreateTransfer** command, but need to know how to use this **-presrc** argument to call a korn shell script(.ksh) or a shell script(.sh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? Although below command is for Windows, I am sure you will be able to modify it to suit Unix. I don't have access to a Unix box to try it.

```
fteCreateTransfer -sa HA2 -sm MFTDEMO -da TARGET -dm MFTDEMO -de overwrite -df C:/MFT/fl1-3.jpg C:/temp/fl1-3.jpg -presrc executable:hello.bat
```

The hello.bat contains the following:

```
copy c:\temp\fl1-1.jpg c:\temp\fl1-3.jpg
```

You need to set the commandPath property in source agent's agent.properties file to point to the path where the shell script exists. For example:

```
commandPath=C:\\Scripts
```

Comment: Is there a way that we can pass a variable (e.g. a reference to the transferred file) to the executable script? (Something similar to variable substitution in the resource monitor)

Comment: You can pass parameters to the executable script - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=reference-examples-using-ftecreatetransfer-start-programs